# Dealing with two versions of the same program in PATH

Tags: linux, bash

I am working on a cluster where I dont have root access and I require a newer version of findutils/xargs than the installed. I installed a newer version in my home and added it to PATH. However, as the old one is also still in PATH, `xargs --version` returns the old version.
Is there an easy way to use the new version or do I need to get in touch with the cluster admins?

Comment: `type -a xargs` should tell you which is where.

Comment: How did you modify `PATH` exactly? Note that the directories listed in the `PATH` variable's value are searched in order and that the shell may hash found executables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATH search is hashed.

If you like to make a new `PATH` to become active evn though a different entry has been in use before call:

```
hash -r
```

Comment: Playing around with hash helped, thanks.